Regarding the rule of introducing a narrative change of character with a new paragraph: Does this still apply if the action is minor?
I am editing a novel. I generally follow the widely endorsed rule of using a new paragraph when introducing a change in dialogue, action or subject.
However, would this still apply when said action is very brief, minor and/or related to the previous sentence?
Here is an example:

“O-oh . . . hello . . .” Sam stuttered, wincing at the thought of what cruelty awaited him. John scoffed.

Or, should it be:

“O-oh . . . hello . . .” Sam stuttered, wincing at the thought of what cruelty awaited him.
John scoffed.

Though I am not personally opposed to the second option, I suppose my concern is that readers may find spacing out every single minor action like this to be tiresome or distracting. But at the same time, I wonder if the first option lacks visual clarity for the change in character, minor as it may be.
I have a feeling that this may be down to personal preference rather than a hard rule, but I am very interested to know your opinions regardless.

If John only makes a non-verbal sound and what Sam says after John makes that sound is more of a continuation of his first utterance, you might keep it all within the same paragraph, e.g.:

"H-hello," Sam stuttered, wincing at the thought of what cruelty awaited him, "n-nice to m-meet you". John laughed. "R-really," Sam continued, trying to ignore John's contemptuous expression, "I-I'm glad y-you are here."
"No," John said. "You are not."
Sam ducked his head and raised his hands in a placating gesture. "B-but I am, J-john."

If what Sam says after John's non-verbal sound is more of a reply to John's sound, that is, if the non-verbal sound is given the status of a turn in the dialogue, you might give it it's own paragraph:

"H-hello," Sam stuttered, wincing at the thought of what cruelty awaited him, "n-nice to m-meet you".
John laughed.
"W-why d-do you a-always l-laugh at me, J-john?" Sam asked.


Point of View:
In a perfect world, you would make each part separate. But each paragraph should really be about who's point of view we are examining. So think about ways that your point-of-view character at that moment is experiencing the event. So for example:

"H-hello," Sam stuttered. John's snort of laughter was all Sam needed to hear to feel humiliated. Mustering his anger, Sam stiffened. "W-why d-do you do that, J-john?"
"Do what?" John asked with an innocent smile creeping over his face. "Like you don't know."

Or consider if this is Sam setting up the situation to confront John.

"H-hello J-john." Sam waited, seething inside, until the inevitable malicious snort of response. "D-do you h-ear your s-self? J-just WHY?"
John blinked. Warily, he replied "What are you talking about?"

Filling the response in in this situation also gives an opportunity to add a bit more detail about the nature and emotional impacts of the scoff.
Or it can give you an opportunity to completely shift the emphasis of the conversation. Let's take the exact dialog from the previous example.

"H-hello," Sam stuttered. Sam watched his friend stiffen and heard john's snort. "W-why d-do you do that, J-john?"
"Do what?" John's Jaw was tight, and his voice shook slightly with suppressed rage. John took a deep breath. His voice was cold. "Like you don't know."

